# How can I extract date out a site using beautiful soup?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I try extracting the date out of this article for example: https://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-5665851,00.html#autoplay

As you can see it appears here:
[image]

But the problem is I don't know how to extract this as it's pure text and not an attribute like datetime or something, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using beautifulsoup and json:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = "https://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-5665851,00.html"
resp = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(resp.text,'lxml') 
#soup receives the response and parses it

data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
#the target is contained inside a script tag; soup now extracts the script and python converts it to text; the converted string is in json format; json.loads() loads it into a variable
print(data['datePublished']) # you can access the info in the variable using the key names (datePublished, in this case)
```

Or you can do it with lxml:

```
import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(resp.text)

targets = doc.xpath("//script[@type='application/ld+json']")
data = json.loads(targets[0].text)
print(data['datePublished'])
```

Output (in both cases):

> 2020-01-25T12:47:27z

Comment: could u explain this? as I don't really know json

Comment: Two things, how come can u reach the datetime variable so easily? and second before I used: session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = {"User-Agent": "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)%22%7D"}
What's the difference?

Comment: Also, I get this error: "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?" @JackFleeting

Comment: @DatGuy - You shouldn't have to; you may have an old version BeautifulSoup. You can also try another parser library (for example, replace 'lxml' with 'html5lib' and see if it works).

Comment: I installed lxml library and I get the error: Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'datePublished'

Comment: @DatGuy - I can't explain it; definitely works for me. The lxml library and the lxml parser in BS4 aren't the same. I'll if I can replicate it using the lxml library.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: now I get this error : Exception Type: ConnectionError
Exception Value: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.ynet.co.ilhttps', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //xnet.ynet.co.il/home/0,7340,L-13789,00.html (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001B79C2262B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))

Comment: @DatGuy - That sounds like a connection problem (either on your end or on the webpage); way of out my pay grade, I'm afraid...

Comment: I just wanted to extract the date :(

Comment: @DatGuy - Try it again in a couple of hours; it may sort itself out.